# OpenAI GYM Register vs. Make

Tags: python, openai-gym

As a beginner in OpenAI gymnasium, my goal is build **SAC from scratch** and use it to train an agent on Bipedalwalker problem.  My question is as follows:

1-  when running the

> `base_env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3", render_mode = 'rgb_array')`

I have this warning

> UserWarning: WARN: Overriding environment GymV26Environment-v0 already
> in registry.

my understanding is that register is used when building my own environment so how else can I react on this warning?